# gitlab heroku api key securing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am doing CI/CD with heroku and gitlab but i found it's not secure placing api in gitlab_ci.yml file

My gitlab looks like:

```
 - dpl --provider=heroku --app=myproject-development --api-key=myapigoesthere
```

I found another way to do it, like this:

```
- dpl --provider=heroku --app=myproject-development --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
```

I found we can give variable this way, but where can i set value of `$HEROKU_API_KEY`?

Anyone knows it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to [set CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#custom-cicd-variables), but you'll specifically want to set it within the [project settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#project-cicd-variables) as a "masked" variable so it doesn't get printed in job logs.

So basically, go to your project's **Settings** > **CI/CD** and expand the **Variables** section and set up a variable with:

- Key: `HEROKU_API_KEY`
- Value: (insert your API key)
- Type: Variable
- Mask variable: on

Save.